# Multiple individual users on one database

Tags: mysql, django

I have a .sql database with which i interact using Django .
The database in the beginning is filled with public data that can be accessed from anynone.
Multiple individual users can add rows into a table(private data).
How can a user see only the changes he made in the database(private data)?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using `django.contrib.auth`.  You just need to do something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# ...

class PrivateData(models.Model):
    # ... private data fields ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then you can get just that user's fields with:

```
PrivateData.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

EDIT: So, if your users are just IP addresses, and you're not using a login mechanism, you don't really need `django.contrib.auth`... though it's good to have anyway since you can use it to authenticate *yourself* and use the built-in admin stuff to manage your site.

If you just want to tie data to IP addresses, set up an `IPUser` model:

```
class IPUser(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True) # Big enough for IPv6
    # Add whatever other discrete (not list) data you want to store with this address.

class PrivateData(models.Model):
    # ... private data fields ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(IPUser)
```

The view function looks something like:

```
def the_view(request):
    remoteAddr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    try:
        theUser = IPUser.objects.get(address=remoteAddr)
    except IPUser.DoesNotExist:
        theUser = IPUser.objects.create(address=remoteAddr)
    userModifiedData = PrivateData.objects.filter(user=theUser)
```

One thing to note: when you're testing this with `manage.py runserver`, you'll need to specify the IP address via environment variable:

```
$ REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1 manage.py runserver
```

When you use Django with a real web server like Apache, the server will set the variable for you.

There are probably several ways to optimize this, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks!I haven't read so much about contrib.auth but if i guess you have to set different user names in order to distinguish them but the only things that can distinguish my users is their ip

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that users have to log into this application.  If yes, add a column to every table for the username.  Add `WHERE username = ?` to every query so they can see only their data.

For data manipulation requests, make sure that the username matches the value for every row; forbid the operation if not true.